# CPU Usage Per Process in Python

Tags: python, monitoring, cpu-usage

Is it possible for me to see the amount of processor usage (% of maximum) that the current, python, app is using?

Scenario: 
My host will allow me to run my app as long as it does not consume more then X% of the CPU power, so I would like it to 'keep an eye on itself' and slowdown.  So how can I know how much CPU the app is using?

Target platform is *nix, however I would like to do it on a Win host also.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.times()
(1.296875, 0.765625, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
>>> print os.times.__doc__
times() -> (utime, stime, cutime, cstime, elapsed_time)

Return a tuple of floating point numbers indicating process times.
```

From the (2.5) manual:

> times( )
>
> Return a 5-tuple of floating point numbers indicating accumulated (processor or other)  times, in seconds. The items are: user time, system time, children's user time, children's system time, and elapsed real time since a fixed point in the past, in that order. See the Unix manual page times(2) or the corresponding Windows Platform API documentation. Availability: Macintosh, Unix, Windows.

Answer (score 13):

By using [psutil](http://code.google.com/p/psutil):

```
>>> import psutil
>>> p = psutil.Process()
>>> p.cpu_times()
cputimes(user=0.06, system=0.03)
>>> p.cpu_percent(interval=1)
0.0
>>>
```

Answer (score 8):

The `resource` module provides [`getrusage`](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/node522.html) which can give you the information you need, at least for Unix-like platforms.

Note that CPU usage as a percentage is always measured over a time interval. Essentially, it is the amount of time taken by your program doing something divided by the interval time.

For example, if your application takes 2 seconds of CPU time over a 5 second period, then it can be said to be using 40% of the CPU.

Note that this calculation, as simple as it seems, can get tricky when using a multiprocessor system. If your application uses 7 seconds of CPU time in 5 seconds of wall clock time on a two-processor system, do you say it is uses 140% or 70% CPU?

Update: As [gimel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276281/cpu-usage-per-process-in-python#276295) mentions, the `os.times` function also provides this information in a platform-independent way. The above calculation notes still apply, of course.

Comment: The problem I see with this is that this is more of a measure of how much CPU time, which although may be helpful, I don't think that it is going to help with this problem, because I need to know that right now appX is using 10% of the total CPU capacity.

Comment: "Right now", every process uses 100% on a single processor system - there is only one process running at any point in time, and it is the one asking for its resource consumption. Take a snapshot of the rusage every second, and then compute how much CPU you have used in the last second.

Answer (score 0):

Use `time.clock()` to get the CPU time.
To get the percentage of CPU usage do CPU time elapsed/time elapsed

For example, if CPU time elapsed is 0.2 and time elapsed is 1 then the cpu usage is 20%.

Note:You have to divide by by number of processers you have. If you have 2 i.e. a dual core:

```
import decimal,timeit
decimal.getcontext().prec=1000
def torture():
    decimal.Decimal(2).sqrt()
    time.sleep(0.1)
import time
clock=time.clock()
while 1:
    clock=timeit.timeit(torture,number=10)
    tclock=time.clock()
    print((tclock-clock)*p)
    clock=tclock
```

Comment: but pay attention MS fans, time.clock() is wall clock time if you're using windows. see python docs here: http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.clock