# Define the Cost of a single process

Tags: python, monitoring

I am currently trying to come up with some business metrics related to how much my web application costs per customer. I know the price we pay per month for servers on amazon and can delimit the number of processes attached to that customer. However, some customers have extra data which incurs extra database overhead, more processes and longer processing. What is the best way to calculate these costs. Since storage is so cheap, and easier to calculate, I want to leave that piece out of the equation for now.

```
#Naive Way
Customer $$ = Cost of Server/Number of Customers
```

Factoring in that some customers have more processes than others

```
#Less Naive Way
Customer $$ = Cost of Server/(% of processes for that Customer)
```

More precise would be to build some tracking into each process, memory usage, system time etc  What should I track and does their exist a package that does this already? (Python preferably as that is is our code base.)

Comment: Please ask a specific programming / programming tools question.

Comment: You might want to might move this to programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: It depends on how your system is designed, I mean if every customer is given an instance then sure you could track the footprint of that instance but you can never monitor something without effecting it so keep that in mind.

Comment: @malvolio how can I move this to the other forum?

Comment: the limited resources on a server are cpu, memory, disk space, disk speed, and bandwidth. disk space is easy to monitor separately, but they should all be factored into cost, because they can all be saturated and cause severe problems if you run out

Comment: @JiminyCricket -- excellent question.  Not a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's your own Python code it is possible for each process to do it's own accounting. The process collects information about itself and submits to the database under the customer id.

The metric here what you are looking for is "CPU time" - how much the process has been using CPU.

[CPU Usage Per Process in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276281/cpu-usage-per-process-in-python)

Also you can get process IO, both disk and network, consumption, in the similar manner. In OSX you should have ready Python calls for these in stdlib (not sure though). On Windows you need to use Pywin32 extensions I believe.