# Confusion in calculating CPU Utilization

Tags: python, linux, unix, linux-kernel, cpu-usage

I am in need of calculating cpu metrics for every 5mins so, I made use of psutil library in python, subtracted the current and old cpuvalue which lead to this.

```
user=5.0, nice=2.0, system=3.0, idle=13.0, iowait=8.0, irq=0.0, softirq=4.0, steal=0.0, guest=1.0, guest_nice=0.0
```

Now I need to calculate total cpu time,

```
total_cpu_time = user+nice+system+idle+iowait+irq+softirq+steal
```

Is the above thing correct or else I have to add guest and guest_nice also

```
total_cpu_time = user+nice+system+idle+iowait+irq+softirq+steal+guest+guest_nice
```

I am little bit sure that guest and guest_nice are included in usermode and nice respectively is my study correct?

Comment: I recommend you have a look at this SO question [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276281/cpu-usage-per-process-in-python) Whether what you're doing is correct probably depends on what you're actually trying to measure.